# How to login with Android app in other Aondroid app?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I have two Android apps **AppA** and **AppB** and now I want to give an option in AppB "Login with AppA" same like `G+` and `FB login`, so what kind of flow need in my both application, **is it possible or not**, please suggest me any related tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: nice question ...........+1 , I think you have to write broadcast receiver with action login and get login credential through intent from other app best of luck

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible with `android:sharedUserId="Your AppB pakacge name"` 
this for only use share preference 
One other way is make AIDL in our project.[AIDL interface link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side application that can link the users database. Simple as that. You build an API for the login in AppA. Then you embed the api calls in AppB too!

Comment: No i dont thing so ..... just same login service in appB would be in use I thing if he use that broadcaster in AppA to call AppB

Comment: Sorry I do not understand but I can't see why an API couldn't do that. I already did it in the past. It works.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's a way for that, if you're saving your credentials inside a **SharePreference** along with  a DB. You can make this **SharedPreference** accessible to other application. The other application can access it by using the package name of the first application.

Comment: I don't think saving credentials in SharedPreferences is a safe solution nor a correct one.